# A TDD Exercise on ConnectFour

Tags: java, unit-testing, connect-four

I'm practicing my TTD skills and trying to apply best practices in Java. I finished (passing all the test cases) the [Connect Four kata](http://agilekatas.co.uk/katas/ConnectFour-Kata) in the Agile Katas and I would like to know if there is a way to improve my [code](https://github.com/selcouthlyBlue/agile_katas/tree/master/connectfour) (this one's updated already).

**ConnectFourGame**

```
public class ConnectFourGame {
    private ConnectFourGrid connectFourGrid;

    public ConnectFourGame(int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns) {
        connectFourGrid = new ConnectFourGrid(numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);
    }

    public void putTokenInColumn(GameToken gameToken, int columnNumber) throws GameIsOverException {
        int rowWhereTokenIsPlaced = connectFourGrid.putTokenInColumn(gameToken, columnNumber);
        checkIfGameIsOverByPlacingTokenIn(columnNumber, rowWhereTokenIsPlaced);
    }

    private void checkIfGameIsOverByPlacingTokenIn(int columnNumber, int rowWhereTokenIsPlaced) throws GameIsOverException {
        GameTokenColor[] connectingTokens = connectFourGrid.getRowOfTokensAlong(rowWhereTokenIsPlaced);
        checkIfThereAreFourConnectingTokensOfTheSameColorInConnectingTokensAlong(connectingTokens, columnNumber);
        connectingTokens = connectFourGrid.getColumnOfTokensAlong(columnNumber);
        checkIfThereAreFourConnectingTokensOfTheSameColorInConnectingTokensAlong(connectingTokens, rowWhereTokenIsPlaced);
        connectingTokens = connectFourGrid.getLeftDiagonalOfTokensAlong(columnNumber, rowWhereTokenIsPlaced);
        checkIfThereAreFourConnectingTokensOfTheSameColorInConnectingTokensAlong(connectingTokens, columnNumber);
        connectingTokens = connectFourGrid.getRightDiagonalOfTokensAlong(columnNumber, rowWhereTokenIsPlaced);
        checkIfThereAreFourConnectingTokensOfTheSameColorInConnectingTokensAlong(connectingTokens, columnNumber);
    }

    private void checkIfThereAreFourConnectingTokensOfTheSameColorInConnectingTokensAlong(GameTokenColor[] connectingTokensIncludingPlacedToken, int indexOfPlacedToken) throws GameIsOverException {
        final int LEFT = 1;
        final int RIGHT = -1;
        checkIfThereAreFourConnectingTokensOfSameColorOnSide(connectingTokensIncludingPlacedToken, indexOfPlacedToken, LEFT);
        checkIfThereAreFourConnectingTokensOfSameColorOnSide(connectingTokensIncludingPlacedToken, indexOfPlacedToken, RIGHT);
    }

    private void checkIfThereAreFourConnectingTokensOfSameColorOnSide(GameTokenColor[] rowOfTokensWhereTokenIsPlaced, int indexOfCurrentlyPlacedToken, int direction) throws GameIsOverException {
        int startingIndex = indexOfCurrentlyPlacedToken + 3 * -direction;
        GameTokenColor colorOfPlacedToken = rowOfTokensWhereTokenIsPlaced[indexOfCurrentlyPlacedToken];
        int numberOfTokensHavingTheSameColorAsPlacedToken = 1;
        for(int index = startingIndex; index != indexOfCurrentlyPlacedToken && isWithinBounds(rowOfTokensWhereTokenIsPlaced, index); index += direction){
            if(areOfDifferentColors(colorOfPlacedToken, rowOfTokensWhereTokenIsPlaced[index]))
                break;
            numberOfTokensHavingTheSameColorAsPlacedToken++;
            if(numberOfTokensHavingTheSameColorAsPlacedToken == 4)
                throw new GameIsOverException(colorOfPlacedToken + " wins!");
        }
    }

    private boolean isWithinBounds(GameTokenColor[] rowOfTokensWhereTokenIsPlaced, int index) {
        return index >= 0 && index < rowOfTokensWhereTokenIsPlaced.length;
    }

    private boolean areOfDifferentColors(GameTokenColor colorOfTokenPlaced, GameTokenColor colorOfConnectingToken) {
        return colorOfTokenPlaced != colorOfConnectingToken;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(connectFourGrid);
    }
}
```

**ConnectFourGrid**

```
public class ConnectFourGrid {
    private List<ConnectFourColumn> connectFourColumns;

    public ConnectFourGrid(int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns) {
        connectFourColumns = Arrays.asList(new ConnectFourColumn[numberOfColumns]);
        for(int i = 0; i < connectFourColumns.size(); i++){
            connectFourColumns.set(i, new ConnectFourColumn(numberOfRows));
        }
    }

    public GameTokenColor[] getRightDiagonalOfTokensAlong(int columnWhereTokenIsPlaced, int rowWhereTokenIsPlaced) {
        GameTokenColor[] gameTokenColors = new GameTokenColor[getNumberOfColumns()];
        for(int rowNumber = rowWhereTokenIsPlaced, columnNumber = columnWhereTokenIsPlaced;
            rowNumber >= 0 && columnNumber < getNumberOfColumns();
            rowNumber--, columnNumber++)
            gameTokenColors[columnNumber] = getColorOfTokenPlacedIn(rowNumber, columnNumber);
        for(int rowNumber = rowWhereTokenIsPlaced, columnNumber = columnWhereTokenIsPlaced;
            rowNumber < getNumberOfRows() && columnNumber >= 0;
            rowNumber++, columnNumber--)
            gameTokenColors[columnNumber] = getColorOfTokenPlacedIn(rowNumber, columnNumber);
        return gameTokenColors;
    }

    public GameTokenColor[] getLeftDiagonalOfTokensAlong(int columnWhereTokenIsPlaced, int rowWhereTokenIsPlaced) {
        GameTokenColor[] gameTokenColors = new GameTokenColor[getNumberOfColumns()];
        for(int rowNumber = rowWhereTokenIsPlaced, columnNumber = columnWhereTokenIsPlaced;
            rowNumber >= 0 && columnNumber >= 0;
            rowNumber--, columnNumber--)
            gameTokenColors[columnNumber] = getColorOfTokenPlacedIn(rowNumber, columnNumber);
        for(int rowNumber = rowWhereTokenIsPlaced, columnNumber = columnWhereTokenIsPlaced;
            rowNumber < getNumberOfRows() && columnNumber < getNumberOfColumns();
            rowNumber++, columnNumber++)
            gameTokenColors[columnNumber] = getColorOfTokenPlacedIn(rowNumber, columnNumber);
        return gameTokenColors;
    }

    public int putTokenInColumn(GameToken gameToken, int columnNumber) throws GameIsOverException {
        checkIfColumnExists(columnNumber);
        return connectFourColumns.get(columnNumber).place(gameToken);
    }

    private void checkIfColumnExists(int columnNumber) {
        if(columnNumber < 0 || columnNumber >= connectFourColumns.size())
            throw new NonexistentColumnException("Column does not exist");
    }

    public GameTokenColor[] getColumnOfTokensAlong(int columnNumber) {
        GameTokenColor[] gameTokenColors = new GameTokenColor[getNumberOfColumns()];
        for(int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < getNumberOfRows(); rowNumber++){
            gameTokenColors[rowNumber] = getColorOfTokenPlacedIn(rowNumber, columnNumber);
        }
        return gameTokenColors;
    }

    private GameTokenColor getColorOfTokenPlacedIn(int rowWhereTokenIsPlaced, int columnNumber) {
        return connectFourColumns.get(columnNumber).getColorOfTokenPlacedIn(rowWhereTokenIsPlaced);
    }

    public GameTokenColor[] getRowOfTokensAlong(int rowWhereTokenIsPlaced) {
        GameTokenColor[] gameTokenColors = new GameTokenColor[getNumberOfColumns()];
        for(int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < getNumberOfColumns(); columnNumber++){
            gameTokenColors[columnNumber] = getColorOfTokenPlacedIn(rowWhereTokenIsPlaced, columnNumber);
        }
        return gameTokenColors;
    }

    public int getNumberOfTokensIn(int columnNumber) {
        checkIfColumnExists(columnNumber);
        return connectFourColumns.get(columnNumber).getCurrentNumberOfTokens();
    }

    public int getNumberOfRows() {
        return connectFourColumns.get(0).getNumberOfRows();
    }

    public int getNumberOfColumns() {
        return connectFourColumns.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < getNumberOfRows(); i++){
            sb.append(Arrays.toString(getRowOfTokensAlong(i)));
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**ConnectFourColumn**

```
public class ConnectFourColumn {
    private List<GameToken> gameTokenRows;
    private int currentIndex;

    public ConnectFourColumn(int numberOfRows) {
        this.gameTokenRows = Arrays.asList(new GameToken[numberOfRows]);
        this.currentIndex = 0;
    }

    public int getNumberOfRows() {
        return gameTokenRows.size();
    }

    public int place(GameToken gameToken) {
        if(columnIsFull())
            throw new FullColumnException("Column is full!");
        gameTokenRows.set(currentIndex, gameToken);
        currentIndex++;
        return currentIndex - 1;
    }

    private boolean columnIsFull() {
        return currentIndex == gameTokenRows.size();
    }

    public int getCurrentNumberOfTokens() {
        return currentIndex;
    }

    public GameTokenColor getColorOfTokenPlacedIn(int rowNumber) {
        if(gameTokenRows.get(rowNumber) == null)
            return GameTokenColor.NULL_COLOR;
        return gameTokenRows.get(rowNumber).getTokenColor();
    }
}
```

---

**Test Code**

**ConnectFourGridTest**

```
public class ConnectFourGridTest {
    private GameToken player1Token;
    private GameToken player2Token;
    private ConnectFourGrid connectFourGrid;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        int numberOfRows = 6;
        int numberOfColumns = 7;
        connectFourGrid = new ConnectFourGrid(numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);
        player1Token = new GameToken(GameTokenColor.BLUE);
        player2Token = new GameToken(GameTokenColor.YELLOW);
    }

    @Test
    public void initializing6x7Grid() throws Exception {
        int expectedNumberOfRows = 6;
        int expectedNumberOfColumns = 7;
        assertTrue(expectedNumberOfRows == connectFourGrid.getNumberOfRows());
        assertTrue(expectedNumberOfColumns == connectFourGrid.getNumberOfColumns());
    }

    @Test
    public void checkingNumberOfTokensInANonExistentColumnShouldRaiseAnException() throws Exception {
        int nonExistentColumn = 7;
        try {
            connectFourGrid.getNumberOfTokensIn(nonExistentColumn);
            fail();
        } catch (NonexistentColumnException ignored) {
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void puttingATokenInAnEmptyColumn() throws Exception {
        int columnNumber = 1;
        placePlayer1TokenIn(columnNumber);
        assertTrue(connectFourGrid.getNumberOfTokensIn(columnNumber) == 1);
    }

    @Test
    public void puttingATokenInColumnWithFiveTokens() throws Exception {
        int columnNumber = 5;
        alternatelyPlaceSixTokensIn(columnNumber);
        assertTrue(connectFourGrid.getNumberOfTokensIn(columnNumber) == 6);
    }

    @Test
    public void placingATokenInAColumnFilledWithTokensShouldRaiseAnException() throws Exception {
        int columnNumber = 6;
        alternatelyPlaceSixTokensIn(columnNumber);
        try{
            placePlayer2TokenIn(columnNumber);
            fail();
        } catch (FullColumnException ignored) {
        }
    }

    private void alternatelyPlaceSixTokensIn(int columnNumber) throws GameIsOverException {
        placePlayer1TokenIn(columnNumber);
        placePlayer2TokenIn(columnNumber);
        placePlayer1TokenIn(columnNumber);
        placePlayer2TokenIn(columnNumber);
        placePlayer1TokenIn(columnNumber);
        placePlayer2TokenIn(columnNumber);
    }

    private void placePlayer2TokenIn(int columnNumber) throws GameIsOverException {
        connectFourGrid.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, columnNumber);
    }

    private void placePlayer1TokenIn(int columnNumber) throws GameIsOverException {
        connectFourGrid.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, columnNumber);
    }

    @Test
    public void placingATokenInANonExistentColumnShouldRaiseAnException() throws Exception {
        int nonExistentColumn = 7;
        try {
            placePlayer1TokenIn(nonExistentColumn);
            fail();
        } catch (NonexistentColumnException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

**ConnectFourGameTest**

```
public class ConnectFourGameTest {
    private ConnectFourGame connectFourGame;
    private GameToken player1Token;
    private GameToken player2Token;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        int numberOfRows = 6;
        int numberOfColumns = 7;
        connectFourGame = new ConnectFourGame(numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);
        player1Token = new GameToken(GameTokenColor.BLUE);
        player2Token = new GameToken(GameTokenColor.YELLOW);
    }

    @Test
    public void aPlayerConnectingFourHorizontalTokensOfSameColorShouldWinTheGame() throws Exception {
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 0);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 1);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 2);
        try {
            connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 3);
            printFailingMessageForNotWinningTheGame(player1Token);
        } catch (GameIsOverException ignore) {
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void aPlayerConnectingFourVerticalTokensOfSameColorShouldWinTheGame() throws Exception {
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 0);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 0);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 0);
        try {
            connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 0);
            printFailingMessageForNotWinningTheGame(player2Token);
        } catch (GameIsOverException ignore) {
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void aPlayerNotConnectingFourVerticalTokensOfSameColorShouldNotWinTheGameYet() throws Exception {
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void aPlayerConnectingFourLeftDiagonalTokensOfSameColorShouldWinTheGame() throws Exception {
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 0);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 1);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 2);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 3);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 0);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 2);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 1);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 3);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 2);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 0);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 1);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 3);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 0);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 1);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 2);
        try {
            connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 3);
            printFailingMessageForNotWinningTheGame(player1Token);
        } catch (GameIsOverException ignored) {
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void aPlayerConnectingFourRightDiagonalTokensShouldWinTheGame() throws Exception {
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 0);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 0);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 0);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 0);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 1);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 1);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 1);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 1);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 2);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 2);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 2);
        connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player1Token, 2);
        try {
            connectFourGame.putTokenInColumn(player2Token, 3);
            printFailingMessageForNotWinningTheGame(player2Token);
        } catch (GameIsOverException ignored) {
        }
    }

    private void printFailingMessageForNotWinningTheGame(GameToken token) {
        fail(String.format("%s should be considered a winner already!", token));
    }
}
```

Comment: please rewind your changes and create a new question. It is pretty hard for others to follow my and Timothy's comments if the original code no longer exists. Please also check my latest update of merging the column into the grid.

Comment: Sorry about that. Rewinded changes already.

Comment: I saw the code you made for merging the column into the grid. It is a nice implementation and all but I think you could have just modified the method getColorOfTokenPlacedIn such that it will use the Token[][] instead of removing the method. This will avoid modifying multiple parts of the code just to accomodate the change. Here's my latest update of the grid: https://github.com/selcouthlyBlue/agile_katas/blob/master/connectfour/src/main/java/Grid.java

Comment: Yeah, this was just feeling. In some cases I would leave it and in other not. There is no real need for either way.

Comment: See "Your algorithm" part of https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/41820/31562

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first impression: too verbose. Usually I'm the one that get complains for too long method/variable names, because I really like this style, but I would try to omit some letters here, e.g.

- `checkIfThereAreFourConnectingTokensOfSameColorOnSide`-> `hasWinningSequence`

You will get in trouble if you want to play 3-wins or 5-wins.

- `rowOfTokensWhereTokenIsPlaced` is confusion, as it is no table row, but might also be a diagonal.
- `checkIfThereAreFourConnectingTokensOfTheSameColorInConnectingTokensAlong`->`completesWinningSequence`

I would prefer a `boolean` return value instead of an Exception for winning.

Think about using an `enum` for your direction instead of `int`. Maybe you want to even use this in a broader sense than left vs. right, but N,W,E,S,SW,NW,NE,SE to also address the diagonal (e.g. horizontal=1/verticial=0 for NORTH, horizontal=+1/verticial=-0 for SOUTHWEST etc.) and iterate thru the tokens in that direction.

Let's think about `void putTokenInColumn(GameToken gameToken, int columnNumber)` in detail and identify the noise adding no information to method:

- `GameToken gameToken`->`GameToken token` (nothing lost)
- `int columnNumber`->`int column` (int and number is redundant, some might even argue that `col` is so common that this abbreviation is also valid)
- `putTokenInColumn` -> `put` (token and column are redundant in the parameter list.

So we get: `void put(GameToken token, int column)` without loosing any knowledge. And the exception is not used, so we can skip it.

In my opinion `ConnectFour` can be omitted in the class names, this is either part of the package name or the application name itself. Also `Color` don't need to be coupled to the `GameToken` that tightly.

The Column array initialization in the Grid is strange. Common pattern would look like:

```
columns = new ArrayList<Column>(numberOfColumns);
for( int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++ )
    columns.add(new Column(numberOfRows));
```

.

Digging deeper it seems that either your Color or your Token is redundant. The Token is only wrapping one Color.

If you test an Exception with try/catch (or better with rules etc.), I recommend to also assert the message of the expected exception. E.g. maybe your are extending your `NonexistentColumnException` later, or will have a message for the lower and one for the upper bound, it is not enough to just check the exception class.

Your mixing of arrays and lists is not that nice. It is totally valid to use both here. This is no high performance application so Lists are fine, but on the order hand the grid is pretty simple so I would prefer using only arrays here. As you don't have different heights per column, your abstraction seems to generic, maybe a two-dimensional array would meet your needs, too.

As mentioned above, modeling the game flow with Exception seems wrong to me (but there are other opinions), but if you do so the `FullColumnException` should be a `RuntimeException` and needs to be part of the method contract.

Check https://github.com/mheinzerling/agile_katas/commit/0511ca9878920960a867221d7c04fd2504011915 for an idea of merging the column into the grid.

Comment: I thank you for your comments. 

I guess my method names and variables are too verbose.  (WIP)

Comment: even with rules you can (and should) verify the exceptions message: `exceptionThrow.expectMassage("Substring, the message should contain");`

Comment: Yes of course. Stupid phrase at my and ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing your code.

I support the answer of @mheinzerling about the long identifier names. I also usually tell peope to be verbose but your's is too much!

Additionally you still have duplicated code: `getRightDiagonalOfTokensAlong()` looks almost the same as `getLeftDiagonalOfTokensAlong()`. There are only small diferences you should refactor out so that you can pass them in as parameters.

I also dislike your approach of splitting up the board into individual *columns* held by a collection in the `Grid` class. This causes a rather complicated logic to check the win condition. Holding all the cells in a `List` or a good old array may have led to a simple logic.

Maybe you like to look at [my approach](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148213/connect-four-the-oo-approach) for reference including the answers I got...

Comment: I just thought that it would be easier to track the current number of tokens in a column if I split up the board into individual columns 'til I saw @mheinzerling's implementation of the Grid. I thank you for your comments as well.